# Python type hinting for upper vs lower-cased strings?

Tags: python

In Python, if I am creating a list of strings, I would type hint like this:

```
from typing import List
list_of_strings : List[str] = []
list_of_strings.append('some string')
list_of_strings.append('some other string')
```

Is there some way to type hint the expected case of the strings? That way, when I write a comparison operator to search for a specific string, for example, I don't accidentally search for the mixed or upper-cased version of a string I know will be lower-cased because all strings in list_of_strings should be lower-cased. I realize I can just add comments and refer back to the list's declaration, but I was wondering if there was a more integrated way to do it.

An alternate way to solve this problem would be to make a class which extends str and rejects any values which aren't in the proper case, and then type hint for that class. Is there any reason why this would be a bad idea aside from it being more of a pain to create than a simple string?

The reason I run into this problem, is that I create lists, dicts, and other structures to store data, then need to add to or search them for a particular key/value and not knowing the expected case creates problems where I add duplicate entries because a simple `if 'example' in string_list` doesn't find it. And doing `if 'example'.upper() in string_list` is easy to forget and not very pretty. Jumping back and forth between the declaration (if I wrote a comment there describing expected case) and where I'm coding distracts from my flow, it would be nice to have the information when I'm referencing that object later.

Comment: You can type hint specific literal values, I don’t think a type hint exists for something *this* specific. Since you’d want to keep such a mechanism generic, you’d need it to run arbitrary validation expressions, which would cease to be *static* type checking. Some sane *naming* of the variable should suffice in practice.

Comment: It is called ***type*** hinting. The type is `str`. Whether the content of the string is lower- or upper-case has nothing to do with the type or type-hinting. If you really wanted, you could create a new type (class) of `UpperCaseString` and another for lower-case but I find it hard to believe it is worth it and has a use case

Comment: *"Is there any reason why this would be a bad idea"* - personally I can't understand the use-case and find it hard to imagine one. It feels like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe try to ask about the actual problem you're having, rather than on on solution you *think* solves it...

Comment: Regarding your last edit: Why not save all strings as lower-case? Before putting in the dict `d[key.lower()] = value` and you know to always do `print(d[key.lower()])` when you want to search for that key

Comment: What if the key is `"Example"`? Neither `.lower()` nor `.upper()` will help here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can in Python 3.10 using `typing.TypeGuard`.

```
from typing import TypeGuard


class LowerStr(str):
    '''a dummy subclass of str, not actually used at runtime'''


def is_lower_str(val: str) -> TypeGuard[LowerStr]:
    return val.islower()


l: list[LowerStr] = []


def append(lst: list[LowerStr], v: str):
    if not is_lower_str(v):
        raise TypeError('oh no')
    lst.append(v)
```

---

You could indeed enforce runtime safety using a subclass of `str`. The disadvantage would mostly be performance. You would want to take care to not add an unnecessary `__dict__`, by adding `__slots__ = ()` to the class definition, from the top of my head.

Either way, string literals are not going to be validated automatically, so it will cause some overhead, either by calling the typeguard, passing them to the constructor of the subtype, or using `cast(LowerStr, 'myliteral')`.

Comment: I just recieved the notification for the unaccept on my answer, but this is a nice-to-know piece of information. Thanks, +1

Answer (score 1):

No, I've been searching on the net for this but it doesn't exist.

The Python's `typing` module doesn't provide any hint for lowercase or uppercase `str`ings.

---

> [...] type hint the expected case of the strings

Remember that a `type` is for example `str`, and in this case you should be talking about `hint` and not about `type hint`.

---

You can anyway create a custom class in this scope:

```
class UppercaseString(str): pass
```

The `UppercaseString` will inherit all the functionalities of the built-in class `str` (that's what happens when you specify `: pass` in `class` declaration).

You can anyway create an `instance`'s `method` that checks if the string is really uppercase, and otherwise raises an error.